# Custom UIView getting display late

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, xib

I'm facing an weird issue, I'm developing a `iOS static library`, this `static library` have some `custom UIViews`. These custom views contains `UIButtons` and `IBOutlets` for those buttons, `Custom UIView` has been create in `Xib`. Now this static library I'm including inside another `static library` and I'm attaching `custom UIView`
of library one in to UIViewController's UIView of static library two with -

```
[self.view addSubview:aCustomViewFromLibrary1];
```

So when I'm using Library 2 in to some product everything goes great but when code of adding `custom UIView` of `static library one` to `static library two` runs everything goes right but `custom UIView` appears late, about half a minutes late.

here is the code for one of the `custom UIView` in `static library` one...

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(!self){
        return nil;
    }
    _otpTextField.delegate = self;
    loadView()
    _approveOtpBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]);
    viewFrame = frame;
    CALayer *layer = self.layer;
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1, 1);
    layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.80f;
    layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:layer.bounds] CGPath];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(!self){
        return nil;
    }

    loadView()
    _approveOtpBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]);

    return self;
}



-(void) awakeFromNib{

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]);
    _approveOtpBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
}

// Approve OTP
-(IBAction)approveOtp:(UIButton *) aButton{

    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]);

}

// minimize custome browser
-(IBAction)minimizeCB:(UIButton *) aButton{
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]);


}

- (void) RegenerateOTP:(UIButton *) aButton{
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__]);
}
```

------**UPDATE**------
This is how I'm adding above `custom View` in the `UIViewController's` `UIView`.

```
- (void) updateView{
if([paymentOption isEqualToString:CHOOSE]){
        if(_choose){
            [_choose removeFromSuperview];
            _choose = nil;
        }
        if(_approveOTP){
            [_approveOTP removeFromSuperview];
            _approveOTP = nil;
        }
        if(_regenOTPView){
            [_regenOTPView removeFromSuperview];
            _regenOTPView = nil;
        }
        _choose =  [[CBAllPaymentOption alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.resultView.frame.size.height - 227,self.resultView.frame.size.width,227)];
        _choose.bankJS = _bankSpecificJavaScriptDict;
        _choose.handler = self;
        NSLog(@"loadJavascript AllOptionView view = %@ ResultView = %@",_choose,_resultView);
        //[_resultView addSubview:_choose];
        if(_connectionHandlerDelegate && [_connectionHandlerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addViewInResultView:)]){
            [_connectionHandlerDelegate addViewInResultView:_choose];
        }
        [_resultView bringSubviewToFront:_choose];
        // view getting display late so call setNeedDisplay.
        [_choose setNeedsDisplay];
        _choose.isViewOnScreen = YES;
    }
}
```

Any solution and suggestion are welcome

Comment: This looks fine besides the addSubview being commented out. Have you got code for the action when a user interacts with this view? You mentioned that nothing appears, but when you tap, it shows up. How about putting setNeedsDisplay as the last thing? Try also wrapping that updateView method in the main thread block in my answer.

Comment: Actually it looks like you're removing the _choose if it exists, then initialising it, but not adding it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you make to the UI must be done on the main thread.

You can try something like this.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  // perform updates here
});
```

Comment: Might need to see the code where you're using this custom view.

Comment: now I'm able to display Custom view but buttons and textfields inside custom view are not being display. any suggestion?

Comment: I need to see more. Need to see these buttons and where you're creating them. They could be hidden, have the wrong frame, not initialised, or just not added as a subview.

Comment: Try logging the frame for these buttons. This way we'll know if they're out of view, or not even created.

Comment: buttons and other controls are always there but not being display, why I'm saying so because when I click on the place where the buttons/controls supposed to be, button get clicked and it appears as well.

Comment: I understand now. This is almost a separate question altogether. Something must be set up incorrectly for this to be happening. I really need to see more code to know whats going on.

Comment: See question update, I have updated the code of adding custom view.
Please have a look and let me know if you can figure it out anything.